How do I remove ads from the Recommended section of my start menu?
I've started seeing advertisements for programs in the Recommended section of my start menu in Windows 11. If I right click the ad I can select "Remove from list", but I'll still get ads for different programs. I've seen Grammarly, TikTok, Hotspot Shield VPN, Evernote, and Match of Empires.
How do I hide advertisements from the Recommended section of my Start Menu in Windows 11?


Courtesy of CNET:


Open your Start menu.
Right-click any blank space and click Start settings
Scroll down until you find the Show recommendations for tips, shortcuts, new apps, and more.
Toggle that setting off.



